# d3 Focus + Context via Brushing not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i am trying to visualize some data using Focus + Context via brushing using D3. I am having some problems with the data. I have just changed the data fetch lines of code since i am fetching 2 values using d3.json. Here is my code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
        margin2 = {top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%a %e %H %M").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
        x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
        y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
        y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
        xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
        yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
        .x(x2)
        .on("brush", brushed);

    var area = d3.svg.area()
        .interpolate("monotone")
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.receiveddate); })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.gtse); });

    var area2 = d3.svg.area()
        .interpolate("monotone")
        .x(function(d) { return x2(d.receiveddate); })
        .y0(height2)
        .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.gtse); });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var focus = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var context = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

    d3.json("rest.php/lastweek"+"/"+"dibya", function(error, data) {
          var allData = data.records;
          allData.forEach(function(d) {
            var formattedDate = new Date(+d.receiveddate).toString();
            d.receiveddate = parseDate(d3.time.format("%a %e %H %M")(new Date(formattedDate)));
            d.gtse = +d.gtse;
          });

          x.domain(d3.extent(allData.map(function(d) { return d.receiveddate; })));
          y.domain([0, d3.max(allData.map(function(d) { return d.gtse; }))]);
          x2.domain(x.domain());
          y2.domain(y.domain());

          focus.append("path")
              .datum(data)
              .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
              .attr("d", area);

          focus.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
              .call(xAxis);

          focus.append("g")
              .attr("class", "y axis")
              .call(yAxis);

          context.append("path")
              .datum(data)
              .attr("d", area2);

          context.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
              .call(xAxis2);

          context.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x brush")
              .call(brush)
            .selectAll("rect")
              .attr("y", -6)
              .attr("height", height2 + 7);
    });

    function brushed() {
      x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
      focus.select("path").attr("d", area);
      focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    }
```

Here the received date is fetched as date in Millis and converted accordingly. The received date is in the frequency of 10 mins. The browser loads the x and y axes according to the values passed but no graph is plotted. Neither do i get any error in console. What am i missing?

Comment: Could you add your complete code or post it somewhere please? It's impossible to figure out why the graph isn't being drawn without seeing the code that is supposed to do it.

Comment: i have edited the question and posted the entire code

Comment: It looks like you're passing `data` instead of `data.records`. Is that the problem?

Comment: oops..... stupid mistake.... Thank you :)